# Who proved that the equilibrium problem is equivalent to a monotone inclusion problem?

Tags: reference-request, convex-optimization

I'm looking for the original reference where it was proved that given a subset $X$ of a space $E$ and a function $f:E \times E \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$, the equilibrium problem of finding $x \in X$ such that $f(x,y) \geq 0$ for all $y \in X$ is equivalent to finding the zero of the monotone operator

$$ T = \partial f(x,\cdot) + N_X(\cdot)$$
where $N_X$ denotes the tangent cone of $X$.

Anyone knows who proved this result first?

Comment: Although I cannot point out to a unique source, this must be quite an old result. It's found for example in Rockafellar's "Convex Analysis" which was published in 1970. This monotone inclusion, however, is a particular instance of the Kuhn-Tucker conditions (involving the subgradient) which were published in the mid 50's. The subgradient was introduced in the 60s by Moreau and Rockafellar, so this result should date back to that time.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no one had an interest in it since almost seven years.